# Convert SQL data into JSON in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have fetch the data by calling stored procedure with arguments by using Python. Now I want my data should come in JSON format. How could I do this ?

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=server_name;"
                      "Database=database_name;"
                      "UID=user;"
                      "PWD=@password;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=no;")

cursor = connection.cursor()

pno = 3 
psize = 2 

sql = "{call [NorthPointCore].[client].[test_python](?, ?)}"
values = (pno, psize)

cursor.execute(sql, (values))


columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

print(results)
```

After running the above code, I get the following result:

```
[{'AsOfDate': '2019-03-27', 'PortfolioName': 'VMFC', 'Strategy': 'CANADA', 'PMStrategy': 'CAD CONVERTS', 'PMTeam': 'CANADA (MANOS)', 'SubStrategy': 'TRE.CVCA', 'SecurityType': 'Equity', 'InvestmentType': None, 'SecurityName': 'EMEXF-USAA', 'InvestmentDescription': 'EMERALD PLANTATION HOLDINGS', 'Ticker': 'EMEXF', 'PositionDirection': 'Long', 'Qty': Decimal('1528493.0000000000000000'), 'MV_Base': Decima03-27', 'PortfolioName': 'VMFC', 'Strategy': 'CANADA', 'PMStrategy': 'CAD CONVERTS', 'PMTeam': 'CANADA (MANOS)', 'SubStrategy': 'BB.CVCA', 'SecurityType': 'Bond', 'InvestmentType': 'Convertible', 'SecurityName': 'BBCN/320SF-CNAA', 'InvestmentDescription': 'BLACKBERRY LTD', 'Ticker': 'BBCN', 'PositionDirection': 'Long', 'Qty': Decimal('19093.0000000000000000'), 'MV_Base': Decimal('0.0000'), 'LongMV': Decimal('0.0000'), 'StartPrice': Decimal('99.5000000000'), 'Price': Decimal('99.5000000000')}]
```

Now I want to convert this above data into JSON, but it keeps saying error : 
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

How could I remove error and get 99.50 instead of Decimal('99.50), in all JSON formats, and get a simple JSON data?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to the edit you added to your question, take a look.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by:

```
# first import json
import json
...
# returns a dict containing all rows
rows = cursor.fetchall() 

# Print rows in json format
print(json.dumps(rows))
```

Edit: `Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable` can be fixed with an serializer

```py
import decimal

def dec_serializer(o):
    if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
        return float(o)


json.dump(results, default=dec_serializer)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later versions, you have got FOR JSON clause to return data as JSON document. Read more about [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). It is more efficient to do in the SQL Side, instead of doing in the python side.

> SELECT id, firstName AS "info.name", lastName AS "info.surname", age,
>   dateOfBirth as dob   FROM People   FOR JSON PATH

Comment: Thx, you help me! :)

Comment: @EndersonMenezes, you are welcome